# Does this line mean right?

Tags: grammar, british-english, spoken-english

I wanted to say to my friend that, I did excercise for 10 mins and after its completion, I waited for 30 mins and then I drank water. I constructed it as

"After 30 mins of doing the excercise, I drank a bottle of water"

But I immediately felt that this line is ambiguous. I think this line could also mean that I did excercise for 30 mins  and then drank water. Was I correct ? If not how should I say it ?

Comment: It is not ambiguous; it means only (not also) what you say. To convey the meaning you intend, say "30 min. after _finishing_ my exercise, I drank a bottle of water.

Comment: Thank you, your sentence structure is much clearer, and if I say "after 30 mins of excercise, I drank water" would that mean that I excercised for 30 mins and then drank water ?

Comment: @AkshitRaj  To your last comment, yes: that's what it means. As Kate is hinting, your original isn't ambiguous, because it is essentially wrong - it doesn't mean what you want it to. I would probably go with: "30 minutes after exercising, I drank a bottle of water."

Comment: @MikeBrockington I have another question, a while ago, I received an email from my college (regarding online exam) , in that email a line was written " exam can be withdrawn within 60 mins of the finish of exam" now I constructed it as meaning that I can withdraw exam within 60 mins after I finish my exam. Is that right ? And is that line grammatically incorrect ?

Comment: @MikeBrockington what are the other ways in which I can say this line ?

Comment: @AkshitRaj  Kate and I have given you two good, and reasonably different examples - is there a problem with either or both of them?

Comment: @MikeBrockington of course not, it is just that I want to know more about English to become better at it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The following works well:

> ### I exercised for 10 minutes. After finishing, I waited for 30 minutes and then I drank some water.

You almost provided an answer to your own question when you wrote, "I wanted to say to my friend that [...]"

Answer (score 1):

If you say *the exercise*, it means you're only doing a single specific exercise. You don't use an article to say that you were exercising in general.

If you want to keep a similar structure to what you wrote, I would say:

> Thirty minutes after I exercised, I drank a bottle of water.